# Powershell Service Account Password Change Logon Failure

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

i am trying to use a powershell script that allows me to change the user account and password a specific service runs under.

```
$account="domain\account"
$password="password"

$svc=gwmi win32_service -filter "name='MyService'"
$svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$false,$account,$password,$null,$null,$null)
```

I could check that the account was changed but when i tried to run the service from the Service.msc GUI it fails with a logon failure.

If I use to start the service from the script itself i get the following error.

```
$svc.StartService()



__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   :

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ReturnValue      : 15
PSComputerName   :
```

According to microsoft it is a logon error : Return Value 15.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I have verified the password a millions time and when I copy and paste the password using the GUI it just works.

May be i am missing something in my script. (SecurityPolicy is unrestricted on this machine)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the SeServiceLogonRight privilege on the user before setting the service account.

```
Set-Privileges $account "SeServiceLogonRight"
$svc=gwmi win32_service -filter "name='MyService'"
$svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$false,$account,$password,$null,$null,$null)
```

An example of the Set-Privileges function which uses LSA:

```
function Set-Privileges
{
    param(    
        $username,
        $Privilege
    )

# C# code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4863/LSA-Functions-Privileges-and-Impersonation
    $Source = @"
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace Privileges {
        public class LsaUtility {

            // Import the LSA functions

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", PreserveSig=true)]
            private static extern UInt32 LsaOpenPolicy(
                ref LSA_UNICODE_STRING SystemName,
                ref LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
                Int32 DesiredAccess,
                out IntPtr PolicyHandle
            );

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true, PreserveSig=true)]
            private static extern int LsaAddAccountRights(
                IntPtr PolicyHandle,
                IntPtr AccountSid,
                LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] UserRights,
                int CountOfRights);

            [DllImport("advapi32")]
            public static extern void FreeSid(IntPtr pSid);

            [DllImport( "advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true, PreserveSig=true)]
            private static extern bool LookupAccountName(
                string lpSystemName, string lpAccountName,
                IntPtr psid,
                ref int cbsid,
                StringBuilder domainName, ref int cbdomainLength, ref int use );

            [DllImport( "advapi32.dll")]
            private static extern bool IsValidSid(IntPtr pSid);

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
            private static extern int LsaClose(IntPtr ObjectHandle);

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            private static extern int GetLastError();

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
            private static extern int LsaNtStatusToWinError(int status);

            // define the structures

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            private struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING {
                public UInt16 Length;
                public UInt16 MaximumLength;
                public IntPtr Buffer;
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            private struct LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES{
                public int Length;
                public IntPtr RootDirectory;
                public LSA_UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
                public UInt32 Attributes;
                public IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
                public IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;}

            // enum all policies

            private enum LSA_AccessPolicy : long{
                POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION = 0x00000001L,
                POLICY_VIEW_AUDIT_INFORMATION = 0x00000002L,
                POLICY_GET_PRIVATE_INFORMATION = 0x00000004L,
                POLICY_TRUST_ADMIN = 0x00000008L,
                POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT = 0x00000010L,
                POLICY_CREATE_SECRET = 0x00000020L,
                POLICY_CREATE_PRIVILEGE = 0x00000040L,
                POLICY_SET_DEFAULT_QUOTA_LIMITS = 0x00000080L,
                POLICY_SET_AUDIT_REQUIREMENTS = 0x00000100L,
                POLICY_AUDIT_LOG_ADMIN = 0x00000200L,
                POLICY_SERVER_ADMIN = 0x00000400L,
                POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES = 0x00000800L,
                POLICY_NOTIFICATION  = 0x00001000L
            }

            /// <summary>Adds a privilege to an account</summary>
            /// <param name="accountName">Name of an account - "domain\account" or only "account"</param>
            /// <param name="privilegeName">Name ofthe privilege</param>
            /// <returns>The windows error code returned by LsaAddAccountRights</returns>
            public static int SetRight(String accountName, String privilegeName){
                int winErrorCode = 0; //contains the last error

                //pointer an size for the SID
                IntPtr sid = IntPtr.Zero;
                int sidSize = 0;
                //StringBuilder and size for the domain name
                StringBuilder domainName = new StringBuilder();
                int nameSize = 0;
                //account-type variable for lookup
                int accountType = 0;

                //get required buffer size
                LookupAccountName(String.Empty, accountName, sid, ref sidSize, domainName, ref nameSize, ref accountType);

                //allocate buffers
                domainName = new StringBuilder(nameSize);
                sid = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sidSize);

                //lookup the SID for the account
                bool result = LookupAccountName(String.Empty, accountName, sid, ref sidSize, domainName, ref nameSize, ref accountType);

                //say what you're doing for debug
                //Console.WriteLine("LookupAccountName result = "+result);
                //Console.WriteLine("IsValidSid: "+IsValidSid(sid));
                //Console.WriteLine("LookupAccountName domainName: "+domainName.ToString());

                if( ! result ){
                    winErrorCode = GetLastError();
                    Console.WriteLine("LookupAccountName failed: "+ winErrorCode);
                }else{

                    //initialize an empty unicode-string
                    LSA_UNICODE_STRING systemName = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING();
                    //combine all policies
                    int access = (int)(
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_AUDIT_LOG_ADMIN |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_CREATE_PRIVILEGE |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_CREATE_SECRET |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_GET_PRIVATE_INFORMATION |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_NOTIFICATION | 
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_SERVER_ADMIN |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_SET_AUDIT_REQUIREMENTS |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_SET_DEFAULT_QUOTA_LIMITS |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_TRUST_ADMIN |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_VIEW_AUDIT_INFORMATION |
                        LSA_AccessPolicy.POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION
                        );
                    //initialize a pointer for the policy handle
                    IntPtr policyHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

                    //these attributes are not used, but LsaOpenPolicy wants them to exists
                    LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes = new LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES();
                    ObjectAttributes.Length = 0;
                    ObjectAttributes.RootDirectory = IntPtr.Zero;
                    ObjectAttributes.Attributes = 0;
                    ObjectAttributes.SecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
                    ObjectAttributes.SecurityQualityOfService = IntPtr.Zero;            

                    //get a policy handle
                    int resultPolicy = (int)LsaOpenPolicy(ref systemName, ref ObjectAttributes, access, out policyHandle);
                    winErrorCode = LsaNtStatusToWinError(resultPolicy);

                    if(winErrorCode != 0){
                        Console.WriteLine("OpenPolicy failed: "+ winErrorCode);
                    }else{
                        //Now that we have the SID an the policy,
                        //we can add rights to the account.

                        //initialize an unicode-string for the privilege name
                        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] userRights = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
                        userRights[0] = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING();
                        userRights[0].Buffer = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(privilegeName);
                        userRights[0].Length = (UInt16)( privilegeName.Length * UnicodeEncoding.CharSize );
                        userRights[0].MaximumLength = (UInt16)( (privilegeName.Length+1) * UnicodeEncoding.CharSize );

                        //add the right to the account
                        int res = LsaAddAccountRights(policyHandle, sid, userRights, 1);
                        winErrorCode = LsaNtStatusToWinError(res);
                        if(winErrorCode != 0){
                            Console.WriteLine("LsaAddAccountRights failed: "+ winErrorCode);
                        }else{
                            Console.WriteLine("LsaAddAccountRights successful");
                        }

                        LsaClose(policyHandle);
                    }
                    FreeSid(sid);
                }

                return winErrorCode;
            }

        }
    }
"@ 

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp  

    [Privileges.LsaUtility]::SetRight($username, $Privilege) | Out-Null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely relevent to this thread but could be useful to someone searching for this type of script.

PowerShell script to scan a computer/server find a service running under a specific account and stop the service, change the password, and then restrart the service.

I used the ListServices.psm1 module, http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-Clear-Printing-21d59516, to make the task easier for me. One quick note which took me a good 15 minutes to troubleshoot, it appears that if one is trying to set a password with a dollar symbol ($) in it, contain it within 'single quotes' not "double quotes"

```powershell
Import-Module "C:\Tools\ListServices.psm1"
$pass = 'H:5Th7$!pc'
$Username = "abcservice"
$compName = gc env:computername
$newpass = [ADSI]"WinNT://$compName/$Username,user"
$newpass.SetPassword($pass)
$newpass.SetInfo()
Get-OSCServiceList -ComputerName "$compName" -UserName "$Username" | select Name | foreach { $_.Name} | Out-file -FilePath "C:\servicelist\service.txt"
foreach ($name in (Get-Content -Path "C:\servicelist\service.txt")) {
  Write-Host "$name"
  Stop-Service "$name"
  Set-OSCServicePSW -ComputerName "$compName" -ServiceName $name -UserName ".\$Username" -    NewPassWord $pass
  Start-Service "$name"
}
```

HTH someone out there.

Comment: Interesting.  Wondering if someone has used this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675577(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I used a different variation from your original script but i keep getting a logon failure.  Wondering if there is a windows policy that restrict this change using a script.

Comment: @Wynn This is interesting. However, I would create a question more relevant to this script, and then put this as the answer (I think with your reputation score < 15, you have to wait 8 hours, though :-(  )

Answer (score 0):

If you are just updating the password for the service account, and not changing which account runs the service, you might have more luck just changing the password itself. I've had success  with this call to Win32_Service.Change():

```
$service.Change($Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Password)
```

This has consistently worked for me to update passwords.

Comment: Well in the beginning when i create the service it uses the LOCAL SYSTEM account so YES. I need to change the user account and the password and then start the service

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stopping the service before changing the password?

The following is working for me

```
$account="domain\account"
$password="password"

$svc=gwmi win32_service -filter "name='MyService'"
$svc.StopService();
$result = $svc.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$false,$account,$password,$null,$null,$null)
if ($result.ReturnValue -eq '0') {write-host "Password changed"} else {write-host "Error: $result.ReturnValue"};
$svc.StartService();
```

Comment: I have a batch file that creates the windows service and initially is stopped. I don't think this will solve my problem

Comment: OK. What is the return value of the password change?

Comment: ```

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ReturnValue      : 5
PSComputerName   :

Password changed
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ReturnValue      : 15
PSComputerName   :
```

Comment: return value ```ReturnValue      : 15```

Comment: I am also seeing a `ReturnValue: 5` which means that the Service Cannot Accept Control, which points to a problem with the service state. Out of interest does your script work on a different service?

Comment: interesting. will need to test with another service and take a look

Comment: The script is provided by teamcity build agent.  Will post the code for that one later.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that your password probably has at least one character that has special meaning in an interpolated string. Try single-quoting:

```
$password='password'
```

In general, it's a better habit to use single quotes by default, and only use double quotes when you specifically want to interpolate something.

BTW, also verify that you're using the correct service name. You need to use the Name property not the DisplayName. Try `gwmi win32_service -filter "name='MyService'"` at the prompt and make sure that doesn't return an error. It's probably the single vs. double quoting issue, though.

Comment: i will try the single quotes and get back to you. Thanks for your suggestion. Not a powershell expert here.

Comment: It didn't work with the single quotes but i am going to proceed to change the password to something simple without any symbols.

Comment: Doesn't work with single quotes and i even tried a stupid 3 letter password.

Comment: Did you verify that it successfully changed the logon account? After invoking **.Change**, run `$svc=gwmi ...` again, then `$svc.StartName`. Also, verify that you can authenticate with that account. One way to do that is `runas /user:domain\account notepad`. Enter the password, and see if notepad starts.

Comment: I have tried using the ```sc.exe config``` but it didn't work out for me. I wonder if any other characters besides alphanumeric are supported with this process. I am using "?" and "@".

Comment: @Maverick: did you try `sc config` in a cmd, to exclude powershell from the equation here ?

Comment: I will come back to this one since the password has been changed to only Alphanumeric

Answer (score -1):

I know this issue was posted several years ago, however, I just encountered the same exact issue, with nearly identical code, resulting in the exact same returns. 
The installer that I am using utilizes subinacl.exe to set permissions. The following article explains how to set those permissions:
http://www.waynezim.com/2010/02/how-to-set-permission-on-a-service-using-subinacl/

I simply added the 'i' switch in installation, and added the user to the appropriate group (if applicable). Considering the age of the article, I hope someone finds this useful.