# Change username and password for services using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to change the username and password for some services using powershell and for that I am using this code

```
$appServices = gwmi win32_service -filter "DisplayName like 'appName%'"
$appServices.change($Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$Null,$username,$password)
$appServices.Startservice()
```

But this doesn't start the services instead it gives the return Value as 15

But if I change it manually by opening services.msc using the same username and password it works
And Sometimes after changing the password manually for one service through services.msc, If I again try to use the same powershell command, it works

Can someone please tell me if I am missing something here

Comment: Result code `15` means "Service Logon Failed: The service does not have the correct authentication to run on the system."  What is the format of `$username`?  [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/change-method-in-class-win32-service) says it can be `DomainName\Username`, `.\Username`, or `Username@DomainName`.

Comment: @BACON I am providing the username in `DomainName\Username` format

Comment: My mistake, that's what `15` means for the `Change()` method.  For `StartService()` it means "The service does not have the correct authentication to run on the system."  Is this a domain, local, or built-in account you're trying to run the service as?  Does that account have the `Log on as a service` right?  When you say it works through `services.msc` do you mean setting the credentials, or starting the service, too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Service Account Password Change Logon Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932343/powershell-service-account-password-change-logon-failure)

Comment: Setting the credentials and starting the service both works when I try it with `services.msc`